# Characterization of Uniform Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, limits, uniform-continuity

If $f:X \to Y$ is uniformly continuous, **then** there exists $\omega : (0, +\infty) \to (0, +\infty)$ with $\lim \limits_{t \to 0^+} \omega(t) = 0$ such that $d_Y(f(x), f(x')) < \omega(d_X(x, x'))$.

I am trying to come up with such an $\omega$ function.

\begin{equation*}
    \omega(t) =t +  \sup \limits_{x \in X, x' \in X} \{d_Y(f(x), f(x')) : d_X(x, x') < t \}
\end{equation*}

I don't know if it makes sense. There will probably be some issues with $\sup$.

Can anyone suggest improvements/corrections?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is called the modulus of continuity.

Recall that if $f: X \to Y$ is uniformly continuous, then $d_X(u, v) \leq \delta(\epsilon) < +\infty$ implies $d_Y(f(u), f(v)) \leq \epsilon$. Let 
$$
\omega(\delta) = \sup\{d_Y(f(u), f(v)) : d_X(u, v) \leq \delta\}.
$$ 
By assumption of uniform continuity, $\omega: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}_+ \cup \{+\infty\}$ and by construction 
$$d_Y(f(u), f(v)) \leq \sup_{d_X(u', v') \leq d_X(u, v)} d_Y(f(u'), f(v')) = \omega(d_X(u, v)), \quad \text{for all}~u, v \in X $$.

We cannot expect that $\omega$ is finite in general. Indeed, consider $f: \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$, where in the preimage it is given the discrete metric $(d_{\rm disc})$, and in the image, it is given the Euclidean metric. Take $f(x) = x$. Then if $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq \omega(1\{x \neq y\})$, we have $\omega(1) \geq |f(x)|$ for all $x \neq 0$. Take $x \to +\infty$, and note then $\omega(1) = +\infty$. On the other hand, if $\epsilon > 0$, then if $d_{\rm disc}(u, v) \leq 0.5$, then $|f(u) - f(v)| = 0 < \epsilon$. Hence, $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Why is $\omega (\delta)$ finite for every $\delta >0$? I think this is what OP is worried about? (If $X$ is a  compact metric space I can see that this is finite).

Comment: Well, I am talking about finiteness on the entire interval $(0,\infty)$.  OP wants a function from $(0,\infty)$ into itself.

Comment: If $d_X$ is the discrete metric on $\mathbb N$ and $f(n)=n$ for  all $n$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous and $\omega (\delta)=\infty$ for  all $\delta >1$. ($Y$ is the real line with the usual metric).

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry my quantifiers were incorrect above. Indeed, it will only hold for $\delta$ small enough.

Comment: When OP said that supremum in the definition may cause problems I think this is what he was worried about. I am unable to see at the moment how to resolve this.

Comment: Is it clear that such function exists? What is it for your example? We necessarily have $\omega(1) = +\infty$, no? Otherwise it implies $|n - m| \leq \omega(1)$ for all $n, m$ distinct, which is clearly false if $\omega(1)$ is finite....

Answer (score 2):

Such a function need not exist. Consider $\mathbb N$ with the discrete metric and let $f(n)=n$ for all $n$. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous. But $|n-1| <\omega (1) \vee \omega (0)$ does not hold for all $n$ whatever your function $\omega$ is.

Here $Y$ is the real line with the usual metric.